# VB.NET: Scope of variables

Tags: vb.net, scope

**Goal:** filling some TextBoxes

**Problem:** when the first `TextBox` is filled, the values of the next ones are compromised. It happens in three steps.

*First step.* Say I have to fill two TextBoxes. A public function does this:

```
Public Sub FillingTextBoxes(Name As String) 
    'Fetching my object from a collection
    Dim newObject As MyClass = MyCollection.Item(Name)

    'Filling two textboxes
    With newObject 
        TextBox1.Text = .Property1.ToString
        TextBox2.Text = .Property2.ToString
```

MyCollection is a public `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection`.

*Second step.* Filling `TextBox1` triggers a `TextChanged` event. Another public function changes the values of the same object:

```
Public Sub SomeOtherFunction(Name As String) 
    Dim newObject As MyClass = MyCollection.Item(Name)
    newObject.Property2 = "something else"
```

*Third step, here it comes.* When `SomeOtherFunction` is done running, back in `FillingTextBoxes`, the value of `newObject.Property2` is now `"something else"`, even though this happened in another function.

How could I possibly solve this?

Comment: That's because a class is a [reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx), also read [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/76153/Six-important-NET-concepts-Stack-heap-value-types).

Comment: @Styxxy: Thanks for the great articles! I already understand better. But is there a way to use my `newObject` as a Value Type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you are storing in the collection is a custom class then you need to implement a `clone` function that allows a **deep copy**.

Clone funcionality allows you to take an object reference and return a new copy of that same type that is a new reference to a different object. For example if you had this:

```
public class MyClass

    public Property1 as string
    public Property2 as string

    public sub new()
        Property1 = string.empty
        Property2 = string.empty
    end sub

    public function clone() as MyClass
        dim returnThis as new MyClass

        returnThis.Property1 = Property1
        returnThis.Property2 = Property2        

        return returnThis
    end function

end class
```

Then you could call for a new deep copy like this:

```
Public Sub SomeOtherFunction(Name As String) 
    Dim newObject As MyClass = MyCollection.Item(Name).clone()
    newObject.Property2 = "something else"
```

And you would have no problems because you are using a new **copy** of the same object instead of the reference in the collection.